# Delete all orders older than specific date by db query

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, delete

I need to delete about 7500 orders and keep the orders from 26.08.2016 and onward. I would like to do it through db query. Is it possible or I have to stick with admin panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this, but backup first in case I'm wrong.
I don't recommend using direct queries because you might end up with zombie data.
You can create a script:

First tell the script that you are on the admin area:

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
```

Then get the orders:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => '2016-08-26'));
```

Now for each order you have to delete the invoices, invoice items, shipments, shipment items, creditnotes, creditnote items, order items, payment references, quote, quote items and in the end the order itself.

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    //delete invoices
    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        //invoice items will be deleted as well
        $invoice->delete();
    }
    //delete invoices
    $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
    foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
        //shipment items will be deleted as well
        $shipment->delete();
    }
    //delete credit notes
    $creditMemos = $order->getCreditmemosCollection();
    foreach ($creditMemos as $creditMemo) {
        //credit note items will be deleted as well
        $creditMemo->delete();
    }
    //delete payment references
    $payments = $order->getPaymentsCollection();
    foreach ($payments as $payment) {
        $payment->delete();
    }
    //delete quote
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());  
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }
        $quote->delete();
    }
    //delete the order. items will be deleted as well. So does addresses.
    $order->delete();
}
```

Comment: Marius I believe in your knowledge, considering all 36 tables related to a single orders,  why do you omit some of tables from your script?

Comment: @Zinat What did I miss? I don't claim it's a perfect script. I can improve it if needed.

Comment: Ah...I see now. I missed the addresses. I'll fix it in a few minutes.

Comment: Consider the list of tables in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento, urfusion's solution.

Comment: For some of the tables, the data will be deleted automatically because of the foreign keys and cascades. For example when you delete a quote item the corresponding records from  `sales_flat_quote_item_option` will be deleted.

Comment: Actually I can even take things out. Because when you delete a shipment for example, the shipment items will be deleted automatically. I also don't need to delete the addresses for the same reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44783/discussion-between-zinat-and-marius).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Delete order Extension to delete the order.
Just select the order between dates, filter it. Selected all that order and select the action from select  box to delete order and submit.

Extension :: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Comment: Actually I'm looking for db query, if possible.

Comment: If you go with direct query then it may possible you will get some issue after some time because there are lots of relation in DB.